# how to load a partial view on button click in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a DDL, on its change I load a partial view _GetX. Right now I am using it like this

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.XId, Model.XList, "Select", new { GetUrl = Url.Action("GetX", "Route") })
```

I need to load this partial view on clicking a button. How do I do this?

Comment: You want to load a partial view when the DDL is changed or when some other button is clicked?

Comment: when some other buton is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `GetX` controller action already returns the partial view:

```
$(function() {
    $('#someButton').click(function() {
        // get the DDL. It would be better to add an id to it
        var ddl = $('#XId');

        // get the url from the ddl
        var url = ddl.attr('GetUrl');

        // get the selected value of the ddl to send it to the action as well
        var selectedValue = ddl.val();

        // send an AJAX request to the controller action passing the currently
        // selected value of the DDL and store the results into
        // some content placeholder           
        $('#somePlaceholder').load(url, { value: selectedValue });

        return false;
    });
});
```